# Losing value of member variable after returning from constructor C++

Tags: c++

Here is the code sample I am working on.

Header file has below code:

```
class TestClass
{
  private:
    LPCWSTR m_variable;
  public:
    TestClass(const std::string& variable);
}
```

Here is the implementation:

```
TestClass::TestClass(const std::string& variable)
{
  std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(variable.begin(), variable.end());
  m_variable= stemp.c_str();
}
```

Here is the code how I make the call

```
std::string tempStr = "Panda";
TestClass *test = new TestClass(tempStr);
```

I stepped through debugger and see that while in constructor the value looks good `L"Panda"`. But as soon as I step out of debugger I no longer see the data for my variable.

Comment: A `LPCWSTR` doesn't store a string; it just points to one.

Comment: Side-note: It's highly unusual to need to use `new` in modern C++. Odds are you really want `TestClass test{tempStr};` to construct it directly in place (use `std::move` if you need to pass ownership to someone else, or `&` if someone needs a non-owning pointer from you temporarily), or if you really need a pointer, use a smart pointer based approach like `auto test = std::make_shared<TestClass>(tempStr);` or `auto test = std::make_unique<TestClass>(tempStr);`. Raw pointers are memory leaks waiting to happen.

Comment: Yes I totally agree, however I am trying to be consistent with existing code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stemp.c_str()` returns a *non-owning* pointer to the contents of the string. And `std::wstring stemp`, which owns the data backing the result of `.c_str()`, ceases to exist the moment you return from the constructor.

Change your class to store a `const std::wstring` directly, so you have an owned, persistent copy of the string. You can then safely call `.c_str()` on the member whenever you need a `LPCWSTR`:

```
class TestClass
{
  private:
    const std::wstring m_variable;
  public:
    TestClass(const std::string& variable);
}

TestClass::TestClass(const std::string& variable) : m_variable(variable.begin(), variable.end()) {}
```